# Yii2 Krajee DateTimePicker - Change plugin-options with Javascript

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I'm using [Krajee DateTimePicker](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datetimepicker), which uses [Bootstrap DateTimePicker](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). I'm trying to change the defaultViewDate option through javascript. Unfortanatly i couldn't target the component correctly with js.

The DateTimePicker widget is defined as followed:

```
echo DatePicker::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'employment_period_from',
    'attribute2' => 'employment_period_to',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'From')],
    'options2' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'To')],
    'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_RANGE,
    'separator' => Yii::t('app', 'to'),
    'form' => $form,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'defaultViewDate' => date('2017-01-01'),
        'format' => 'yyyy.mm.dd',
        'autoclose' => true,
    ]
]);
```

I already tried:

```
$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").defaultViewDate('2012-01-01');
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('setDefaultViewDate', '2012-01-01')
```

with no success; gives me js erros: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

So is there a way todo so?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
added an *id* to the widget and used the *kvDatepicker* function

```
...
'id' => 'datepickerWidget',
...
```

and now i tried the follwoing

```
$('#datepickerWidget').kvDatepicker('setDefaultViewDate', '2012-01-01')
```

which at least doesn't give me an error; still doesn't change anything...